# Probability of drawing three balls of white colour

Tags: probability

A bag contains 5 White,7 black, 4 Red balls. Find the probability that three balls drawn at random are white.

**My attempt:**

The sample space for drawing 3 balls is {WWW,BBB,RRR,WBB,WRR,RBB,RWW,BRR,BWW}. So required probability is 1/9. But answer given is 1/56. Where am I wrong?

Comment: You draw your conclusion from expecting that the probability of drawing each ball is the same when it clearly isn't - obviously, drawing a white ball should be more likely than drawing a red ball, but less likely than drawing a black one.

Comment: Do you think the answer still would be $\frac 19$ if the bag contained $3$ white balls, $1000$ black balls, and $1000$ red balls?  But if those were the numbers, your calculation would remain exactly the same.  That's a clue that your analysis can't be right.

Comment: $\frac{5\times 4\times 3}{16\times 15\times 14}$

Comment: @cosmo5 its given they are taken at random all at once. Permutations wont matter.

Comment: Right, then @AndrewChin explained the reason nicely.

Comment: If the balls are taken all at once, then we want the probability of selecting three of the white white balls when selecting three of the $5 + 7 + 4 = 16$ balls, which is $\frac{\dbinom{5}{3}}{\dbinom{16}{3}}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In total, there are 16 balls and you need the probability of picking 3 white balls.
You can consider 3 different cases each time you pick a ball, and then multiply the probabilities to get the desired answer.

> Pick 1:
> Total balls: 16
> White balls: 5
> Probability of picking white P(w): $5\over16$

> Pick 2:
> Total: 15
> White: 4
> P(w): $4\over15$

> Pick 2:
> Total: 14
> White: 3
> P(w): $3\over14$

Now that you have got the individual probabilities, the total probability of drawing 3 white balls is: $P(3W)=P(\text{W in Pick 1})\times P(\text{W in Pick 2})\times P(\text{W in Pick 3})=\Large\frac{5}{16}\times \frac{4}{15}\times \frac{3}{14}=\frac{1}{56}$